# Assign different multimedia functions (like a notebook setup) to F1-F12 keys on desktop computers?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-computer, function-keys, fn-key

I want to attribute multimedia functions to <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys on a desktop computer.

I know they have standard functions (like renaming a file with <kbd>F2</kbd>) but It would be way more useful If I could use <kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> to increase/lower the computer volume, and etc, pretty much notebook standard stuff.

Is there a user friendly, or not, way to do that?

Comment: the standard way is to use [sharpkeys](https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/) or AutoHotkey to remap: [How to remap special keys on Asus laptop?](https://superuser.com/q/170238/241386), [Generic way to remap every media button](https://superuser.com/q/1055166/241386), [Remapping Function Keys for media vs. Alt + Function Key for specific app](https://superuser.com/q/1274002/241386), [How to Remap "Home" button on a Local Multimedia Keyboard without Driver](https://superuser.com/q/990914/241386), [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/q/36920/241386)